# Short story where algae runs a kind of software simulation of another world where life is evolving

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about an ocean planet where there are huge mats of algae and no other life. The algae appears dumb but on a cellular level it's running a simulation of another world, and life is evolving in the sim. Some of the life seems to be self aware.

I hope this is accurate, it's been years since I read it. I think I read this in either *Asimov's* or one of those big anthology books like *The Year's Best Science Fiction*.

Comment: Hi! Please see [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to help improve this. First, when did you read this?

Comment: Yes, Wang's Carpets appeared in Gardner Dozois' [13th annual collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction:_Thirteenth_Annual_Collection) and was included in Dozois' ["Best of the Best" collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_of_the_Best:_20_Years_of_the_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction) which is, if I may add, an absolute must-have with many exceptional and outright moving stories.

Comment: This is clearly not, but reminds me of, Nemesis by Isaac Asimov

Comment: Fun fact: Conway's Game of Life (aka [cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)) is Turing complete.  ([What is Turing Complete?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1610655)).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation#Models.  I assume this story was inspired by that fact (and the strong-AI hypothesis that human consciousness isn't "special" and can be simulated computationally by a Turing-equivalent machine)

Comment: Also similar to Sirens of Titan by Kurt Vonnegut

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe this is "Wang's Carpets" ([isfdb entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41714)) by Greg Egan, a story that formed the basis for the later novel [*Diaspora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(novel)).

It was published in the *New Legends* anthology edited by Greg Bear.

Human consciousness is now running in software, and have been travelling the universe seeking other life. They find a waterworld with large "carpets" moving slowly through the ocean. The humans realise that the carpets are actually running a simulation through their growth, and there may be sentient beings within the simulation.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I'm pretty sure this is it, and I get to read a novel now :D

Comment: I just finished Diaspora. Wang's carpets was one of the many mind blowing concepts in the novel. They're made of complex carbohydrates, IIRC, and are based on [Wang Tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile). In the 60s Wang showed that they are turing complete, and can thus execute any computation.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the carpet-growth calculation wasn't deduced to necessarily be a simulation _per se_, but rather just a sign of deliberation.  That is, maybe it's simulating sentient beings, or maybe the growth is the sentience itself.  But that's all a nitpick and timbp's answer is correct in all the important parts; it's a great story!

Comment: Answer copied over to https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/dlq9wa/short_story_where_algae_runs_a_kind_of_software/ where this was cross-posted, just to link them together. :)

Comment: FWIW,  time inside a CA (cellular automaton) world would run very slowly compared to the outside world: computations inside a CA tend to be slow. Patterns that do a specific computation (eg calculating [Fibonacci numbers](https://www.conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=81#p281) in binary) aren't too bad, but if you need a "programmable" pattern then it can easily take a huge number of CA generations per step in the computation. Eg, the [Gemini spaceship](https://www.conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=81#p281) takes 33,699,586 generations to rebuild itself.